# JFrame's default icon showing intermittently in Win taskbar during dynamic updates

Tags: java, swing, jframe, imageicon

I am dynamically updating the icon of a `JFrame` but in the task bar the default icon (cup of coffee) is showing every few seconds, is there any way to disable it?

First I set a default custom icons:

```
frame.setIconImage
```

And then update the icon every 100 ms. Tested in Win 7/8/10 (oracle jdk 8 and 10) - same behaviour.

This is for my audio player to visualise audio waves.

[image]

Any way to fix it?

Sample code:

```
package test;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class TestFrameIcon {

    static BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(64, 64, BufferedImage.TYPE_4BYTE_ABGR);
    static Random r = new Random();

    private static BufferedImage getIcon() {
        Graphics g = img.getGraphics();
        g.setColor(new Color(r.nextInt(255), r.nextInt(255), r.nextInt(255)));
        g.fillRect(0, 0, img.getWidth(), img.getHeight());
        g.dispose();
        return img;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame f = new JFrame();

        f.setIconImage(getIcon());
        f.setSize(100, 100);
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        new Thread(() -> {
            while (true) {
                f.setIconImage(getIcon());
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                }
            }
        }).start();;
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

Every few seconds it is showing a default icon in the task bar:

[image]

Comment: For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). Replace the sound spectrum with a random animation.

Comment: BTW - it's possible to make an MCVE of this problem that is less than 50 LOC. Can you add one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code provided keeps reusing the same BufferedImage, the one that's already in use.

Try allocating a new BufferedImage for each update. Don't worry too much about creating lots of crap on the heap, it will get cleaned up quickly. If you absolutely require no extra objects on the heap, swap between two BufferedImages.

Comment: Did you try this in combination with the EDT answer above?

Answer (score 1):

I could reproduce the problem.

I disappeared when I made sure the change of icon is performed in the Event-Dispatch-Thread like this (for Java 8 and higher).

Replace

```
f.setIconImage(getIcon());
```

with

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> f.setIconImage(getIcon()));
```

Comment: Thanks, I also tried this, and it seems to help a bit, but it is still showing the default icon every ~ 5 second or so.

Comment: I think you already noticed that it is possible to have several icons on a window. The idea is that you could provide several different sizes of the same icon. I think you should investigate this. Is it possible to remove the default icon completely?

Comment: Yeah I tried to use a list of different sizes (16,20,24,32,48,96,256) - doesn't help.

Comment: *"I also tried this"* Ditto, and my example was both started the GUI on the EDT, with all changes to the GUI performed from within the EDT. OP: Would you like me to edit the question to add my ('better practice' example code)?